# Kubernetes Nginx ingress multiple ExternalIps

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I install `Nginx Ingress Controller` on bare metal.
[image]

now i want to add many ExternalIP , 10.24.100.55  10.24.100.56 , 10.24.100.57

This is my `Deploy.yaml`

```
spec:
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - appProtocol: http
    name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - appProtocol: https
    name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  externalIPs:
    - 10.24.100.55
  type: NodePort
```

When i try to add other ips , there is error
For example

```
externalIPs:
        - 10.24.100.55 , 10.24.100.56
```

is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
externalIPs:
   - 10.24.100.55 , 10.24.100.56
```

Try:

```
externalIPs:
- 10.24.100.55
- 10.24.100.56
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add external IP addresses, the externalIPs option permits kube-proxy to route traffic sent to arbitrary IP addresses and on the Service ports to the endpoints of that Service.As per the official Kubernetes documentation you can add you external ip in "my-service" under spec section, you can find the details in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips).

One could set the following external IPs in the Service spec, and NGINX would become available on both the NodePort and the Service port after that give the following commands.

```
$ curl -D- http://myapp.example.com:port
```

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Server: nginx/1.15.2

```
$ curl -D- http://myapp.example.com
```

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Server: nginx/1.15.2

The myapp.example.com subdomain above resolves to both 2 IP addresses we have given.

For more information follow [External IP’s](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#external-ips).